# WPF How to stop animation from a thread in background worker

Tags: wpf, animation, backgroundworker

I have a task that takes a long time. I do it with a background worker thread and before start it, since Do_Work I begin an animation over a label and when task finishes, I stop it in RunWorkerCompleted but I received an error because I try to begin/stop animation in the background thread that is not the owner. How can I do this, I mean to begin/stop animation in the background worker?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should start the animation before starting the `BackgroundWorker`, not in the `DoWork` event. That way, you will be able to stop it from the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the  [Dispatcher.BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx) method, on the control which is doing the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the stop animation on the UI thread using something like the following:

```
private void OnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    /* If not operating on the main UI thread, call this method again on the App dispatcher's thread */
    if (App.Current != null && App.Current.Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(OnRunWorkerCompleted), new object[] { sender, e});
        return;
    }

    // Do stuff to the UI here
}
```